# Add read more to label and expanding UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am populating a UITableView with labels. How can i add a "read more" button at the end of the label only if the number of characters in that label exceed 120 and make the UItableViewCell expand to fit the new big label? Please help. (SWIFT)

Comment: There is a very nice highly configurable library available [see this](https://github.com/OpenFibers/DragRefreshAndLoadMoreTableDemo)

Comment: I need something in swift, so i can configure it directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you will have to manually adjust the string as it goes into the label, turn it into a `NSAttributedString` with 120 characters (with the ....) then append a `NSLinkAttributeName` for the `read more` part with a dummy URL, override `textView shouldInteractWithURL` and put expand function there (which should be just reload the cell with full string)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you provide me with some details pls about how can i expand the label height before reloading data? What about the constraints related to that label?

Comment: If your cell only have a label, then just pin 4 side to the cell and let it automatically calculate the height with `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`, then you can just change the label's string and call tableView's `beginUpdate` and `endUpdate` to let it update the height

Comment: No, that's not the case. I have an image with not constant height under the label. So i just can't pin the 4 sides.

Comment: It doesn't matter, the automatically calculate can work with more than one dynamic height view also, you just need to make one of them have different `content hugging priority` and pin the label and image to 4 side around them, you can search more about how to create automatically tableViewCell height around here

Answer (score 1):

Just a Swift 3 version of @VRAwesome answer:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    var height: CGFloat = 333

    // assign initial height
    let lblFrame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(40), y: CGFloat(50), width: CGFloat(194), height: CGFloat(50))

    //assign initial frame
    let strText = currentChallenge.description as NSString
    let rect = strText.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: lblFrame.size.width, height: CGFloat(Float.greatestFiniteMagnitude)), options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin, .usesFontLeading], context: nil)

    if rect.size.height > lblFrame.size.height || rect.size.height < lblFrame.size.height {
        let diff = rect.size.height - lblFrame.size.height
        height = height + diff + 20
    }

    if isRowOpen[indexPath.row] == true {

        let rect = strSharedText.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: lblFrame.size.width, height: CGFloat(Float.greatestFiniteMagnitude)), options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin, .usesFontLeading], context: nil)

        if rect.size.height > lblFrame.size.height || rect.size.height < lblFrame.size.height {
            let diff = rect.size.height - lblFrame.size.height;
            height = height + diff + 20;
        }
    }

    return height
}
```

Comment: Where is strSharedText coming from? You're answer lacks of logic comments and your algorithm is not working.

Comment: All I did was convert another anser into the latest version of swift without changing anything. You can refer any comments to the original autho @vrawesome

Answer (score 0):

First calculate chars of string which you are going to assign to label. If that is more than 120 chars then create and add button(Read More) to the bottom right corner of cell.

[image: Read More & Expand]

And when press `Read More` then calculate size of string using `boundingRectWithSize` then reload that particular cell it will update size of cell.

Create one global `boolean` array :

```
bool isRowOpen[];
```

Your methods should be like :

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CGFloat height = 420; // assign initial height
    CGRect lblFrame = CGRectMake(40, 50, 194, 50); //assign initial frame

    NSString *strText = [someArray objectAtIndex:indexPAth.row];
    CGRect rect = [strText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(lblFrame.size.width, FLT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading context:nil];

    if (rect.size.height > lblFrame.size.height || rect.size.height < lblFrame.size.height) {
        float diff = rect.size.height - lblFrame.size.height;
        height = height+diff+20;
    }

    if (isRowOpen[indexPath.row] == TRUE) {

        CGRect rect = [strSharedText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(lblFrame.size.width, FLT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading context:nil];

        if (rect.size.height > lblFrame.size.height || rect.size.height < lblFrame.size.height) {
            float diff = rect.size.height - lblFrame.size.height;
            height = height+diff+20;
        }
    }
    return height;
}
```

And last on `Button` `Read More` click event reload that particular cell. when you want expand, update `isRowOpen[selectedRow] = TRUE`. when you want collapse then again update `isRowOpen[selectedRow] = FALSE`. So it will show effect what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. But I need it in swift if it's possible.

Comment: where does `strSharedText` come from?